# Origin of the formula Varswap strike $= \int_{\mathbb R} I^2(d_2) n(d_2)\, \mathrm d d_2$

Tags: variance-swap

As stated in the title, who first derived the formula
$$
\text{Varswap strike} = \int_{\mathbb R} I^2(d_2) n(d_2) \, \mathrm d d_2
$$
where $d_2$ is the Black-Scholes quantity
$$
d_2 = \frac{ \log S_t/K}{I\sqrt{T-t}} - \frac{I\sqrt{T-t}}{2}
$$
and $n(d_2)$ is the standard normal density function?

The earliest reference I could find is to a GS paper by Morokoff et al., Risk management of volatility and variance swaps, Firmwide Risk Quantititave Modelling Notes, Goldman Sachs, 1999.

Is this then the source, i.e. the formula can be attributed to Morokoff?

Comment: In an Oct 1999 paper Morokoff claims to have derived formula (18), closely related to your formula,  in the above cited paper https://www.risk.net/sites/default/files/import_unmanaged/risk.net/data/Pay_per_view/risk/technical/1999/risk_1099_swaps.pdf . This kind of self-citing is not a guarantee however, there could be some other earlier source.

Comment: @nbbo2 Yes, the risk paper does some self-citing. I think only someone who worked at GS in those days can say something more about this.